# Is there a way to save svn console log (in subclipse) in a file?

Tags: svn, logging, console, subclipse

In our company we deal with a lot of plugins and projects. Thats why we have some automated import-mechanism when setting up a workspace.

The svn console is buffered, which make sense considering performance.

When error occurs with svn (connection, etc.) these informations are lost if the buffer is to small.

Is there a way to save these informations without altering the buffer, suggested in
"https://eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/preferences/pref_console.php"